# How to create a class MyString which has a method to implement replacing substrings in Java?

Tags: java, string

I have a small homework in java which I'm still not familiar with. I tried multiple times sadly I have got incorrect results I'm a beginner in this programming language so anyone who could kindly help me with this!

Here is the question: Let's say the original String is:

"He is 9-year-old boy. He is quite tall for his age. But he is quite shy."

I should replace all "is" with "was"

The expected output should be: "He was 9-year-old boy. He was quite tall for his age. But he was quite shy."

Here are what I did:

```
public class BlockTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyString s = new MyString();

       s.changeString();


    }
}


class MyString{

    public static String changeString(){
        String original = "He is a 9-year-old boy. He is quite tall for his age. But he is quite shy.";
        String search = "is";
        String sub = "was";
        String result = "";
        int l;
        do{
            System.out.println(original);
            l = original.indexOf(search);
            if(l != -1){
                result = original.substring(3, 4);
                result = result + sub;
                result = result + original.substring(l + search.length());
                original = result;
            }

        }while(l != -1);

        return result;
    }
}
```

It gives unexpected output, which is:

He is a 9-year-old boy. He is quite tall for his age. But he is quite shy.

iwas a 9-year-old boy. He is quite tall for his age. But he is quite shy.

swas quite tall for his age. But he is quite shy.

swas age. But he is quite shy.

swas quite shy.

Comment: Java already has replace functions. I don't know if your homework parameters allow you to use (call) them. For reference:
https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-replace-replacefirst-replaceall-method-examples/

Comment: use original.replace("is","was");

Comment: Why `original.substring(3,4)`?

Comment: rahulP, your suggestion will replace all `"is"` with `"was"`, even inside words.  It should be using a regexp replacement  `original.replaceAll("\\bis\\b", "was");` where `\\b` means a word border, but this could be too much for a beginner.

Comment: If you need your code to work, you should change setting of a prefix before the detected `search` to `result = original.substring(0, l);`  Also, you should look for " is" to avoid replacement inside words (e.g., "his" becomes "hwas").

Comment: It is not allowed to use any other methods from the String class (like: replace(); or replaceAll() ), the method which is inside MyString class supposes to do that instead.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with "do-while" which I have used here

Answer (score 0):

You can use **public String replaceAll(String regex, String replace_str)** which is an inbuilt method in *String* class of JAVA.

```
 String str = "He ...... shy.";
 str = str.replaceAll(" is ", " was ");
```

**Note:** Here I have used space before after the word *"is"* and *"was"*.
          If u will not do it then words like *"his"* will be replaced with *"hwas"* which we don't want here.